# Substracting of blur filters

Tags: image, filter, blur

Could someone please describe me what the result of the substraction of a small blur filter from a large blur filter is? ...

So I perform an average blur filter on an image. One time with size, let's say 5 and one time with 10.

When I substract the results now (filter(10)-filter(5)) what, in words, is the result of that ? How is it described in words?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Also, the answer is: it could be anything, depending on the specifics of your blur functions.

Comment: I tried it in GIMP (Phothoshop would work) and it looks like a "blurred" edge detector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the blur filters, this can have the effect of an edge detector or sharpener.  The [Difference Of Gaussians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians) operation is basically what you described when the blur filters are Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is determining selective edges (as the filter sizes vary the edges will also vary).